# Can't run docker in Centos 7

Tags: docker, centos7

I installed docker following the official website instructions, yet I get the following (from `journalctl -xe`):

```
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.614348477Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.646352167Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.646395968Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.646438441Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.646482278Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.648745422Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.648780339Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.648824261Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.648847918Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.650640781Z" level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: no such device" storage-driver=overlay2
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.652619063Z" level=error msg="AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems" storage-driver=aufs
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.653285845Z" level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: no such device" storage-driver=overlay
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.678262705Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support oom control"
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.678323247Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness"
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.678339101Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit"
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.678352245Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory TCP limit"
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.678365163Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.678378018Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: time="2021-09-12T11:15:16.678391295Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find pids cgroup in mounts"
Sep 12 11:15:16 myhostname dockerd[18504]: failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

System Information:
`OS`: Centos 7
`Kernel Version`: 3.10

The output of `cat /etc/os-release` is:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

The output of `uname -r` is:

```
3.10.0-042stab141.3
```

Comment: While the version number *here* was also a clue that this could be a kernel built for OpenVZ, a kernel number this old is always a clue that something is off. While RedHat certainly does a better job than some others, correctly backporting fixes to ancient releases is one heck of a difficult task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "virtual machine" VPS is not actually a VM, but an OpenVZ container. You cannot run Docker in this environment. Purchase a different VPS which does not use OpenVZ.

Comment: You are absolutly right, I just realized that Godaddy hosting is really a bad choice.